# Need to capture SSL_PROTOCOL details in access log of HttpServer

Tags: apache, websphere, httpserver, ibmhttpserver

We try to identify the ssl_protocol is using when it communicated to Inbound Connectivity and so we tried to append this attribute `\"%{SSL_PROTOCOL }e\"` under `LogFormat` in `httpd.conf` file.

We formatted as  in below manner.

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %T\"%r\" %>s %b \"%{SSL_PROTOCOL}e\" " common
```

But still we are not able to capture the `SSL_PROTOCOL` details. Is that any pre-requisite needs to be done or any other alternative is to be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IBM HTTP Server uses `%{SSL_PROTOCOL_VERSION}e` and `%{HTTPS_CIPHER}e` for the handshake details.